# How to test with Selenium RC js function's return

Tags: javascript, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I got JS function defined in some js file on page, which returns object. 
If i try to get result from console Myfunc returns `function()`, and `Myfunc.[some arguments]` returns `object`.
If I try to get result with storeEval from Selenium I got

> [error] Threw an exception: Myfunc is not defined.

What should I do to get result?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Selenium 2, you can take advantage of web driver's ExecuteScript method to run arbitrary javascript in the browser.  In C# it would look like this:

```
object myobj = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return myfunc();");
```

You can [check out the documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) to see the syntax for Java, Ruby or Python.

Comment: Thanx for reply. I'm using PHPUnit (will add to question). Googled about it - looks there is something for me, but still it is buggy :(

Comment: You might want to check out facebook's php-webdriver project.  In their example wiki, they show how to execute javascript. https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Example-command-reference